# How to prevent the transformation of special signs in URI?

Tags: c#, unicode, uri

Im trying to use the Win8-Searchbar for scan through a http-Server.

```
string uriString = "http://myServer:myPort/?ItemList,SQLFilter=Title LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%'";
Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);
```

Special signs like "%", " "(Whitespace) are getting transformed to "%25", "%20" ...

How can I prevent these transformation? The http-Server doesn´t understand it :(

Comment: Are you really building SQL queries from your url parameters ?

Comment: "...the app is only a prototype for internal (intranet) experiments..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp),

> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
>
> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.
>
> URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.

That's why URL Encoding occurs and there's no way to avoid it.

On the server side you need to use [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) to decode the string.

---

### Not related to the problem, but extremely important:

Exposing something like `SQLFilter=Title LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%'"` in the URL represents a huge security issue. **Anyone can modify that to run arbitrary statements on your DB**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I have to contact our server-administrator to adapt it. We know about the security issue, the app is only a prototype for internal (intranet) experiments. Thank you for that.